# Windows не пингует Linux

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, ip

есть 2 компа один win10 второй Ubuntu Server. Оба подключены к роутеру и получают ip по dhcp, linux машина пингует виндовс а виндовс машина не хочет пинговать linux машину. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Отключите Firewall или добавьте правило, разрешающие пингование.

Comment: *не хочет пинговать* - это из разряда "у меня в подполе происходит стук". Цитируйте выводимое сообщение (destination unreacheable, timeout, general error, etc.).

Comment: @Akina на windows машине пишет `Обмен пакетами с 192.168.100.10 по с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 192.168.100.2: Заданный узел недоступен.
Ответ от 192.168.100.2: Заданный узел недоступен.` и почему то перенаправляет с `.10` на `.2`

Comment: Никто ничего не перенаправляет. `192.168.100.2` - это адрес сетевого интерфейса машины, с которой выполняется пинг (то есть windows-станции). Сообщение говорит о том, что станция знает, как послать пакет узлу назначения, но при попытке послать его получает от кого-то ответ, что узел недоступен. И 99% за то, что это локальный брандмауэр (если бы блокирование было в ubuntu - было бы получено сообщение о тайм-ауте). Настройте его. В первом приближении - хотя бы выберите тип сети этого интерфейса.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте firewall на машине с Ubuntu.

```
iptables -vL
```

Скорее всего, firewall отфильтровывает входящие пакеты icmp.
Тогда в таблице FILTER вы увидите строку наподобие:

```
target  prot opt in     out     source               destination 
DROP    icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Тогда нужно перед ним добавить разрешение принимать запросы ping:

```
iptables -I INPUT <номер правила> -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: `iptables -vL` выводит вообще кучу всего, и какой номер правила добавлять?

Comment: @user1 iptables -vL | grep icmp для теста присутствия блокирующего правила. А номер правила - для теста работоспособности хоть первым, но лучше (в целях производительности, потому что пакеты тестируются на соответствие правилам с первого и дальше) - прямо перед блокирующим правилом. И само собой никак не после блокирующего правила. Номер вы определите у себя в системе.

Comment: я все это делю собственно что бы подключится по ssh обратите пожалуйста внимание на мой предыдущий вопрос просто мне так и не дали внятного ответа может вы будите знать как мне помочь. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756903/Не-работает-сеть-между-компьютерами